# TeamCity can't locate any artifacts after a build

Tags: .net, msbuild, teamcity

I have a build in TeamCity which runs against a project file names Web.csproj (inside a "Web" folder in the root) and targets "Package". It runs just fine and I get a nice Web\obj\Debug\Package folder with all the expected content.

I then have a second build with an artifact dependency on the above path which is intended to run the deploy command. However, no matter what I do I always get a "Failed to download artifact dependency" error message followed by "No files matched for pattern "Web/obj/Debug/Package"". Even if I set the artifacts path to just ** and try to pull everything from the root, it fails. Looking on the server, there are clearly files in the working directory.

Does anyone have any guidance for troubleshooting this?

Comment: Does the first step list all the artifacts after a successful build, in the TC status screen?

Comment: note: You have to specify on the first step what to output as artifacts, by default there are none.

Comment: Spot on Lasse, I didn't have the previous step creating the artifacts (still getting to grips with the concepts I'm afraid). Would you like yo leave that as the answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, the answer was that I hadn't defined an artefact path in the first build. Without specifying the output to save from this build, it won't be available in dependent builds.